# How to setup Ubuntu 16.04 with multiple HDD's

Tags: hard-drive, desktop-environments, sshd

I'm reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 in my Box. I have a 128 gig ssd running the system from root. I also have two 500 gig hdd's and a 1tb hdd. I can't mount them all in the same place for some reason so I had to mount one @ /home, another @ /usr and the last (1tb) @ /usr/local.

Is this the dumbest thing ever or am I doing the right thing?

Comment: The answer depends on what you want the system to do (where do you need to hold large volumes of data and you are not too worried about the access speed). If you want to mount all of the disks in the same place (for example a 2 GB home disk) you could use lvm to amalgamate all of the disks into a logical volule you could mount at (say) home

Comment: That's really what I want to do but

Comment: @Nick Sillito  That's really what I want to do but I only know how to install and mount at instalation.  I'm gonna Google LVM right now

Comment: Keep your entire / (root) on SSD. You can use LVM, but be aware that if one drive fails you lose all data. So good backups are vital. Advantages/Disadvantages LVM Post #9
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1586328&p=9917145#post9917145
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm I prefer to use data partition(s) and mount those into my /home.